# How to set a Label.Text from a specific Column of an Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an MS Access Contacts database file, with tables `[Contact]` and `[Email]`.
Each contact can have multiple email addresses.
The `Emails` table has a "Primary" boolean Column, I am unchecking all other "Primary" cells associated with a specific contact, so each contact can only have 1 primary email address.
That is the value I am trying to retrieve from the database and display in `Label1` on a DataRepeater control.

Here is my code trying to get the primary email address from the list of email addresses for a contact:

```
Try
    Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dbSource As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Data\Contacts.accdb"
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim connString As String = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [E-mail Address] FROM Email WHERE ContactID='" & BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Text & "' AND Primary=True ", con)
    Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

The problem is the `Label1.Text` still shows `Label1` when I run the program.
I know this is incorrect, but I am unable to find a solid example to pull a value from a specific cell and assign it to a label like I am trying to do.

Exception:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in
>   criteria expression.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()    at
>   Contacts_AccessDB.Form2.ContactBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users...\Contacts-AccessDB\Form2.vb:line
>   73

UPDATE:
This answer was provided in a comment, but is advised not to use because it is not using parameters:

```
Try
    Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dbSource As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Data\Contacts.accdb"
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim connString As String = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [E-mail Address] FROM Email WHERE ContactID=" & BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Text & " AND Primary=True ", con)
    Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

And here is what I am currently doing:

```
Try
    Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dbSource As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Data\Contacts.accdb"
    Dim connString As String = dbProvider & dbSource
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [E-Mail Address] FROM Email WHERE ContactID=@ContactID AND Primary=True ", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Text.Trim)
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            Label1.Text = reader.Item(0).ToString()
        End If
        conn.Close()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: _E-mail Address_ is this a single field? Then you need square brackets around it _[E-mail Address]_ Are these two fields? Then you need a comma to separate them _E-mail, Address_ Anyway that query cannot work. Do you have an empty exception block around these lines of code?

Comment: How do you avoid multiple? Primary` for a contact? If you improve your data-structure (normalization is the first you should do!)m by adding a field to contacts-table that contains the primary key of the main email, you don't have to care about that and you get the adress by a simple lookuo.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys!  I have updated the original post, including the error I am now getting.  "ContactID" is the name of the column in the [Email] table.  The `BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Text` is the current position, and it is showing the correct ContactID when debugging.

Comment: If ContactID is a numeric field in your database then you don't need to put single quotes around the string concatenation above that forms your query. Probably this will solve the problem, but you need to consider how to write Parameterized query in future. Also boolean fields are queried with 0 for false or -1 for true (not sure if its 1 form MS-Access db)

Comment: @user9343037 `Primary` is a SQL Kwyword, maybe needs to be escaped by enclosing with square-brackets. And @Steve may have found another flaw. Compare `[Primary] <> 0`for false

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - is that correct?  I followed the guide but it doesn't look like it changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. I changed your code to use parameters instead.

I did not check for errors in the code below but you should add some code to handle errors.

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection( connString),
cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [E-Mail Address] FROM Email WHERE ContactID=@ContactID AND Primary=True ", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(BindingNavigatorPositionItem.Text.Trim)
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows AndAlso reader.Read()
        Label1.Text = reader.Item(0).ToString()
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: This will not work if a non-existant ContactID is passed as value

Comment: @preciousbetine - I have checked this as the answer, but I do not have enough rep to upvote it.  I have updated the OP, showing how I got your example to work.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user9343037 No P. if u can't upvote. You're welcome! Happy New year!