# Label Databinding on DataRepeater with Subqueries

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am making a contact manager Windows Forms App in VB.NET with an Access DB.  A contact in this DataBase can have multiple email addresses, but only 1 of them can be `primary` which I am controlling in code for only 1 email address to be the primary email address for that contact: if a new email address is checked as `primary` then it unchecks the other rows for the current contact. Note: `Primary` is the name of the Boolean column, not the PK column.  Tables are setup like this:

```
Contact Table                       Email Table
[ContactID]     Integer PK column   [EmailID]       Integer PK column
[Name]          String              [Email Address] String
                                    [ContactID]     Integer FK column related to Contact.ContactID
                                    [Primary]       Boolean
```

I received help on getting the text for a label earlier [How to set a Label.Text from a specific Column of an Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554313/how-to-set-a-label-text-from-a-specific-column-of-an-access-db), which can pull just the email address that is checked in the primary column.  However, the same `Label.Text` appears on all the indexes in the data repeater.  It actually makes sense now why it behaves this way, because there is no where to set the Label1.Text property when it is filling with data from the DB.

Bound controls pulled from the Data Sources window in Visual Studio display the correct information on the data repeater control.  I have been unsuccessful dropping a label on the data repeater and have it display the correct email address for each contact (i.e. If Contact #1 has an email john.smith@acmecorp it will display properly, but that same label is applied to all indexes on the data repeater control and Contact #2 displays the same email instead of jane.doe@acmecorp.com)

I am hoping to get some direction on how to solve this, because nearly all solutions I can find are using ASP.NET which do not appear to be applicable because the same events for data repeaters are not available in VB.  I'm not sure if there is a simple way to programmatically databind the label so each index displays differently, or if I have to create a new DataTable and populate it with all the values and data bind it to the data repeater control instead of the `ContactEmailBindingSource` I am using now.

Edit:
When I try to set the databinding on the Label1 I attempt to add this query:

```
SELECT        Email.[E-mail Address]
FROM            (Email INNER JOIN
                         Contact ON Email.ContactID = Contact.ContactID)
WHERE        (Email.[Primary] = True)
```

And I receive a Search Criteria Builder Error:

```
The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query.
```

Update:
[ContactsTest.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qd_miZZOpJ8-uwBkWu_kouddhccO70B1)

Working example of answer provided.

**Final Update:**

I honestly didn't know what I was supposed to look up to resolve this issue, and after several searches I come across creating subqueries.  It took a bit longer to actually get implemented than I had hoped, but now I have a proof of concept that can be used, and sharing here for anyone who requires this type of functionality.

Requires a `DataGridView1` & `Button1` on the form, then insert this code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        Dim dbSource As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Data\ContactsDB.accdb"
        Dim connString As String = dbProvider & dbSource
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim query1 As String = "SELECT   [ContactID], 
                                         [ContactName], "

        Dim query2 As String = "(SELECT  [Email Address]
                                 FROM    [EmailsTable]
                                 WHERE   [ContactsTable].[ContactID] = [ContactID]
                                 AND     [Primary] = True)
                                 AS PrimaryEmail "

        Dim query3 As String = "From [ContactsTable];"

        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connString),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(query1 + query2 + query3, cn)

            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

        End Using

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
End Class
```

Working example of what I was trying to achieve.

[ContactsTest2.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M2wQUvCb-7Dlcv9_LJpNKw8KNR4DVxOX)

NOTE: I skipped using a DataRepeater for this example to simplify it.  To use labels on a data repeater control simply add this after `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)` and it will display the email address on Label1 that you have put on the DataRepeater.ItemTemplate:

```
Label1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", dt, "PrimaryEmail"))
```

Comment: Can we see the select command you are using to bind the controls? It seems a Join is in order.

Comment: What goes into [Contact Table.Email] ?

Comment: @Mary - [Contact Table.Email] was not correct.  There is no Email column on the Contact table, and I have corrected that in the OP, as well as posted the query I have tried on a label that was put onto the data repeater.  Would it help to see the query for the other controls that are working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have a DataRepeater handy so I just displayed the data in a DataGridView.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.ContactsConnect),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select [Contact Table].ContactID, 
                                            [Contact Table.Name], 
                                            [Email Table].[Email Address] 
                                            From [Contact Table] 
                                            Inner Join [Email Table] On [Contact Table].ContactID = [Email Table].ContactID 
                                            Where [Email Table].Primary = True;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

I took your table names literally. You will need to correct to the real table names.

Comment: This project is part of a larger project and I could not get your code to work, so I created a new Access DB file and Visual Studio project, modified the query to match, and this works exactly like I needed it to.  I have updated the OP with a working example for others who come across the same issue.  Thank you so much for your assistance!  I've accepted the answer, and as soon as I get 15 rep I can upvote it.

Comment: I just determined the reason I could not get this to work with my original code was it will not display anything if there are no email addresses set to primary.  But this does get me one step closer to what I need.

Comment: @user9343037 The Where clause will limit the returned records to only those that have Primary = True.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a working example that resolves the issue I was facing.  I'm still keeping this as the answer because it resolved exactly what I had initially asked for.